# Who is the man in the suit in the Fullmetal Alchemist series?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

Does anyone have any clues on the man in the suit? He appears in both FMA and FMA:B.

Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood, *Separate Destinations* (episode 10)

[image]

Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood, *Footsteps of a Comrade-in-Arms* (episode 16)

[image]

Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood, *Advance of the Fool* (episode 21)

[image]

Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood, *Backs in the Distance* (episode 22)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be of any help in this case, but do you have any idea if this man also appears in the manga?

Comment: Hes re-used to lower the budget of drawing new characters

Comment: @BDillan: sorry about my earlier comment; there was a typo. I meant to say that there were supposedly _less_ instances of reused character designs in the manga than in either anime series.

Comment: Apparently this guy is called the "cameo guy" on forums.

Answer (score 19):

After searching everywhere for the day looking this up before someone else finds the answer, he appears to be Mobuta Mobuo. He is actually a background character that was actually placed in their as a joke as said in an interview with Arakawa Hiromu in the Perfect Guidebook (Hagaren Kenkyujo DX). He was also a gag character in the Mangas and hardly anyone seemed to notice him.

[image]
[image]

I am absolutely sure this is him.

---

Bibliography for reference

1. http://www.roy-mustang.net/arakawa/about_interview1.html

Included for reference to my answer, to verify that this information is correct and to allow you to compare this information with other information to see if this is correct.

Comment: Mobuta Mobuo? That's hilarious - _mobu_ means "background character".

Comment: @senshin- Lol, i know right. It's funny how Arakawa named him.